# Stored procedure input parameters validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE procedure usp_insert_abm_tctrol_ch   
    (@cod_suc numeric(3), 
     @id_bco numeric(3),
     @cod_banco numeric(3),
     @nro_cta VARCHAR(15),
     @fec_activa SMALLDATETIME,
     @fec_inactiva SMALLDATETIME,
     @nro_ch_desde numeric(9),
     @nro_ch_hasta numeric(9),
     @ult_nro_ch numeric(9),
     @sn_ch_inicio numeric(3),
     @tipo_chequera VARCHAR(2), 
     @sn_estadoi_ch INT,
     @sn_estadof_ch  INT)
as  
begin 
    declare @error varchar(500)

    begin try
    begin tran 
        set @error = ''
        set @error = 'hubo un error'

        if @error <> ''  
        begin    
            RAISERROR(@Error, 16, 10)  
        end   

        insert into tctrol_ch (cod_suc, id_bco, cod_banco, nro_cta, fec_activa, fec_inactiva, nro_ch_desde, nro_ch_hasta, ult_nro_ch, sn_ch_inicio, tipo_chequera, sn_estadoi_ch, sn_estadof_ch) 
            select 
                @cod_suc, @id_bco, @cod_banco, @nro_cta, @fec_activa,
                @fec_inactiva, @nro_ch_desde, @nro_ch_hasta, @ult_nro_ch,
                @sn_ch_inicio, @tipo_chequera, @sn_estadoi_ch, @sn_estadof_ch 
        commit tran 
     end try 
     begin catch
        rollback tran

        declare @Err varchar(max)

        set @Err = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        RAISERROR(@Err , 16, 10)  
     end catch
```

I want to validate that the `@nro_cta` (number account) belongs to the current bank (`@id_bco`). How can I do that?

I have a table "Bank" that have a column name "nro_cta". I would like to verify it with an if statement. I'm a beginner to stored procedures, thank you!

Comment: So I indented your code to make it readable -- notice how you set a variable and then test it right away?  Also, there are a number of incomplete statements -- this is a big pile of code that means nothing.

Comment: You would do that validation with a select statement. We can't possibly help you because you haven't provided any details about the table or what you want to do.

Comment: The simplest way to check is if bank account exists is `IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM [bank] WHERE nro_cta =  @nro_cta`. You can then take some action inside your if condition.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add something like

```
declare @testbank numeric(3)

SET @testbank = (SELECT id_bco from Bank WHERE nro_cta = @nro_cta)

If @testbank <> @id_bco OR @testbank IS NULL
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Wrong bank', 16, 10)
    END
```

I can't be absolutely sure because although you say that Bank has a field nro_cta, you do not say what field the bank id is called, so I am guessing it is id_bco for consistency's sake.

Also for this to work I am assuming that id_bco and nro_cta are the same data types as @id_bco and @nro_cta.

Comment: Would be a bit simpler with an exists check but I too am guessing this is along the lines of what they want.

Comment: @SeanLange I thought of using IF EXISTS where account = account and bank = bank (note you have to have the 'and') but then thought he may well want to do something different if the account belonged to a different bank.  Just using if exists only tells you there's something wrong: it could be bank doesn't exist, account doesn't exist or account in wrong bank.  I was trying to point him towards a way to gain a bit more info, if there is an error.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't trying to insinuate there was anything wrong with this approach at all. We are all guessing since the OP provided almost nothing in the way of details.

Comment: you can simply your T-Sql: SELECT a_testbank = id_bco from Bank WHERE nro_cta = a_nro_cta. Please, change 'a_' as '@'